# What's the 3 minute countdown for after defeating the Beast fights?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-4-guns-of-patriots

After defeating any of the B&B bosses they turn from beast to beauty form and attempt to hug you to death. I'm not sure if there's a hidden timer but after messing around with the hugging beauty for a while, the screen goes white and there's just Snake and the Beauty left on screen (with the UI) and a 3 minute countdown timer. What does this timer represent?

Answer (score 6):

It is over after 3 minutes, they colapse and die. But as stated it is a sort of easter egg.

> When their Beauty forms are advancing upon the player, not killing them for several minutes will result in transportation to an infinitely sized White Room, with a three minute timer. It is impossible to call Otacon or Rosemary while in this room. Equipping the camera will cause the Beauties to pose. If the player selects and de-selects the camera, they will change their pose. Equipping the iPod and playing "Oishii Two-han Seikatsu" will make them dance. When the timer expires, the Beauties collapse and die.

[Source](http://metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/The_Beauty_and_the_Beast_Unit)

Comment: So its a timed photo shoot event similar to what the Metal Gear Solid: VR Missions had. I think its worth noting that if the timer expires during this photo shoot event, it will count as a lethal kill and Snake will not get the corresponding face-camo or the beauty statue.